# Why does the following code print logs even after the game object is detroyed?

Tags: unity

I have the following in a script attached to a game object in a unity scene. When I run this scene and press 'E', I get the following logs. (The game object is destroyed too)

**In destroy**
**After destroy**

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)){
        Debug.Log ("In destroy");
        Destroy (gameObject);
        Debug.Log ("After destroy");
    }
}
```

My question is that if the game object is destroyed, then why does the execution continue to the code which logs "After destroy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for this. As per the Unity documentation ([at this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)), the actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop. Therefore, the current update method is executed and the logs are printed.

Answer (score 3):

It's just finishing the current frame as the task in the same frame on `Update()`.

If you test like below you will not see anything form next frame. `LateUpdate()` is executed in next the frame after `Update()` execution.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Debug.Log("In destroy");
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Debug.Log("After destroy");
    }
}
```